# Finding A of a matrix representation of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrix representation of a linear transformation:
$[Lv]_E = A[v]_E$;  How do you find $A$?

Here we assume that $L \colon V \to V$ is a linear transformation, and $E$ is a basis of the vector space $V$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your notation means? I assume that $L : V \to W$ is the linear transformation between vector spaces $V$ and $W$, $v \in V$, and $E$ is a basis of $V$. Also, since you've only specified $E$, I assume $W = V$ with the same basis $E$. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct.///////

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of $V$ as an abstract vector space over a field $\mathbb F$ of scalars. Write the basis $E$ of $V$ as a list $E = (e_1, \dots, e_n)$ of abstract vectors. The point of a basis is that *every* abstract vector $v \in V$ may be written *uniquely* as a linear combination of the basis vectors, 
$$
v = v_1 e_1 + \cdots + v_n e_n \in V,
\tag{1}
$$
where the coefficients $v_i \in \mathbb F$ are scalars. Then the data $v \in V$ and $(v_1, \dots, v_n) \in \mathbb F^n$ are equivalent. In your notation, we might write 
$$
[v]_E = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb F^n.
\tag{2}
$$
We say this is "$v$ written in the basis $E$" or "$v$ with respect to the basis $E$" or "the coordinate vector of $v$". This gives us a (vector space) isomorphism between abstract vectors $v \in V$ (on the left) and $n$-tuples of scalars (on the right), i.e.,
$$
[a u + bv]_E = a \begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\ \vdots \\ u_n \end{bmatrix} + b \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{bmatrix}
\tag{3}
$$
for any scalars $a,b \in \mathbb F$ and vectors $u, v \in V$. We can easily figure out one side of the equation from the other.

Now, we want to characterize the action of a linear transformation $L$. For any $v \in V$, we have
$$
Lv = L(v_1 e_1 + \cdots v_n e_n) = v_1 L e_1 + \cdots + v_n L e_n,
\tag{4}
$$
so if we know only the $n$ vectors $L e_1, \dots, L e_n$, we can compute $Lv$ from them (using the scalars in $[v]_E$). Now we write $Le_i$ in terms of the basis $E$:
$$
[L e_i]_E = \begin{bmatrix} a_{1,i} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n,i} \end{bmatrix},
\tag{5}
$$
so
\begin{align*}
[Lv]_E &= [v_1 Le_1 + \cdots + v_n L e_n]_E && \mbox{By (4)} \\
&= v_1 [L e_1]_E + \cdots + v_n [L e_n]_E && \mbox{By (3)} \\
&= v_1 \begin{bmatrix} a_{1,1} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n,1} \end{bmatrix} + \cdots + v_n \begin{bmatrix} a_{1,n} \\ \vdots \\ a_{n,n} \end{bmatrix} && \mbox{By (5)} \\
&= \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} a_{1,1} & \cdots & a_{1,n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n,1} & \cdots & a_{n,n} \end{bmatrix}}_{A} \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{bmatrix} \\
&= A [v]_E,
\end{align*}
where the last line is the matrix-vector multiplication you're used to. By this equation, the matrix $A$ encodes all of the information about how to compute $L$; given $v \in V$, write its coordinate vector $[v]_E$, multiply by the matrix $A$, and then change back from coordinate vectors to abstract vectors (if desired).

Just as we had an isomorphism between abstract vectors and coordinate vectors
$$
v \leftrightarrow [v]_E = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ \vdots \\ v_n \end{bmatrix},
$$
we have an isomorphism between linear transformations and matrices with scalar entries:
$$
L \leftrightarrow A = \begin{bmatrix} a_{1,1} & \cdots & a_{1,n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n,1} & \cdots & a_{n,n} \end{bmatrix}.
$$

---

With that being said, the way I find most useful to think of this is the following. Given $L$, to write down its matrix, make an array with basis vectors on the outside
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
& e_1 & \cdots & e_j & \cdots & e_n \\ \hline 
e_1  \\
\vdots  \\
e_i  \\
\vdots  \\
e_n  \\
\end{array}
$$
and then in column $j$, write the scalars in the coordinate vector $[Le_j]_E$
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
& e_1 & \cdots & e_j & \cdots & e_n \\ \hline 
e_1 & a_{1,1} & & a_{1,j} & & a_{1,n} \\
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
e_i & a_{i,1} & & a_{i,j} & & a_{i,n}\\
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
e_n & a_{n,1} & & a_{n,j} & & a_{n,n} \\
\end{array}.
$$
to get the inner array to be the matrix $A$. From this we see that $A$ is the matrix whose $i,j$-entry $a_{i,j}$ is the $i$th scalar in the coordinate vector $[Le_j]_E$. And matrix-vector multiplication works out how you're used to!

Answer (score 1):

Start with the basis $E= \{e_1,\ldots,e_m\}$.

Then, calculate $L e_j$ and write it in the basis $E$ as $\sum_{i} a_{ij} e_{i}$. Then, $A$ is the matrix with $ij$-th entry $a_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $g \colon V \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by $g(v) = [v]_E$, then the application $[v]_E \mapsto [Lv]_E$ can be written as $$g \circ L \circ g^{-1} \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n.$$ This shows that it is a linear application. Moreover the matrix $A$ that represents this linear application is determined by the action of $g \circ L \circ g^{-1}$ on the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, namely $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$. In particular, if $E = \{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$, then the $i$-th column of $A$ will be $$g(L(g^{-1}(e_i))) = g(L(u_i)) = [L(u_i)]_E.$$
In other words, the $i$-th column is given by the coordinates with respect to $E$ of the image under $L$ of the $i$-th vector in the bases $E$.